# How to create a frame for AsTableNode in AsyncDisplayKit?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, asyncdisplaykit

I used `facebook's AsyncDisplayKi`t to run my project, Where I found a sample project named "**ASDKgram**". It uses Nodes instead of TableViewCells. By default, the '`AsTableNodes`' aka TableView are displayed to the bounds of the screen.

I want my `tableView` or `AsTableNodes` to be displayed `10pixels` from each edge of the uiScreen.

**Question:** How can I create the AsTableNodes with that specific frame?

If anybody had already gone through the `AsyncDisplayKit`, Please respond with an answer.

Here is the link to that project https://github.com/facebook/AsyncDisplayKit/tree/master/examples/ASDKgram

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ASCollectionNode

First, replace

```
tableNode = [[ASTableNode alloc] init];
```

with

```
tableNode = [[ASCollectionNode alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:[UICollectionViewFlowLayout new]];
```

Then add this to ASViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  _tableNode.view.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10);
}

- (ASSizeRange)collectionView:(ASCollectionView *)collectionView constrainedSizeForNodeAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  return ASSizeRangeMake(
          CGSizeMake(0, 0),
          CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 2*10, CGFLOAT_MAX)
  );
}

- (NSInteger)collectionNode:(ASCollectionNode *)collectionNode numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return [_photoFeed numberOfItemsInFeed];
}

- (ASCellNodeBlock)collectionNode:(ASCollectionNode *)collectionNode nodeBlockForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  PhotoModel *photoModel = [_photoFeed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  // this will be executed on a background thread - important to make sure it's thread safe
  ASCellNode *(^ASCellNodeBlock)() = ^ASCellNode *() {
      PhotoCellNode *cellNode = [[PhotoCellNode alloc] initWithPhotoObject:photoModel];
      return cellNode;
  };

  return ASCellNodeBlock;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Let me check on that, And will get back to You

Comment: I changed table to collectionnode... It works perfeclty now